# Python3 script hangs after successful execution

Tags: python-3.x

I have a Py3 script that uses threading a queuing. It connects to multiple network elements to collect and analyze data. It connects to 100-300 devices concurrently, depending on the inspection length. After the script checked all the devices it sends a CSV report. It arrives successfully, but the crontab does not send the email report because the script does not exit.

```
$ uname -a
Linux vendor01 3.10.0-957.10.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Feb 7 07:12:53 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ python3
Python 3.6.3 (default, Apr 10 2019, 14:37:36) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)] on linux

pgrep -af python3
42137 python3 al_hcheck_v4.py
pkill -f al_hcheck_v4.py
```

After killing the process crontab report arrives via email. The last print statement - how long it took to run - is there, but the script had to be terminated.

```
2021-07-21 01:50:53 Completed, disconnecting zzzzzzzzz host index 1

Batch time taken: 120.20165872573853 seconds.
Next node batch 100 : None.

Failed to process: []

Hosts skipped due to Unknown error: []

Hosts skipped due to DNS error: []

Total time taken: 1412.880184173584 seconds.

/home/xxxxx/start_al_hc.sh: line 6: 42137 Terminated              python3 al_hcheck_v4.py
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Failing to stop generally suggests that one thread is left hanging. Could you provide a minimum reproducible example of your thread code, showing when threads exit/join?